# How to eliminate the problem of AlertDialog in my project

Tags: java

I am having problem with my code, when I type

```
AlertDialog waitingDialog= new SpotsDialog(MainActivity.this);
```

the whole line is underline" a message pop out saying

> requires android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog but found dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog
>
> implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'

I have added this:

```
if (edtPassword.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Password too short", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    return;
}
final AlertDialog waitingDialog = new SpotsDialog(MainActivity.this);
waitingDialog.show();
```

Comment: it would appear you are using the wrong type of dialog

Comment: try deleting the `import` for the `SpotsDialog` and be careful which one you add - probably multiple options will be available.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong type of AlertDialog.
Your error message states:

> requires android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

You can see on it that you are using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog) implementation `(android.support.v7.app)` of AlertDialog, but SpotsDialog implements [this one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog) `(android.app)`  - as can be seen on the [implementation](https://github.com/d-max/spots-dialog/blob/master/library/src/main/java/dmax/dialog/SpotsDialog.java) on row 6.

You should change our AlertDialog import to:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```